# Changing checkbox background in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making a Win32 application and now I'm trying to implement CheckBoxes but I'm not capable of changing their color separately, does anybody know how to do that?

Ive tried this:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
        return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    }
```

My main goal is to make their background transparent but not all of them (some of them must be colored).

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not supported by the standard button control. You're going to have to roll your own, if you need a transparent background.

Comment: `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` ?

Comment: You have to owner-draw the checkbox in order to change its appearance.

Comment: As far as I remember the check box control (actually a button control) sends a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message to its parent window. Handle this message to draw a different background underneath the checkbox.

Comment: Could you provide a schematic diagram of what exactly you want to achieve?